# Generating mapping dictionary of composite object in python

Tags: python, dictionary, magic-methods

I need a method in a composite class to return the mapping of the instance.

```
class Component:
    def __init___(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Entity:
   def __init__(self, component, c, d):
       self.component= component
       self.c = c
       self.d = d

   def as_dict(self):
       mapping_dict = self.__dict__
       mapping_dict['component'] = self.component.__dict__
       return mapping_dict
```

This solution will only work once when `as_dict()` method is called for the first time. When it's called for the second time, this would not work since `self.entity` will now refer to a dictionary and calling `__dict__` on it will raise `AttributeError`.

So I came up with a not so efficient solution;

```
def as_dict(self):
    temp_1 = temp_2 = deepcopy(self)
    mapping_dict = temp_1.__dict__
    mapping_dict['component'] = temp_2.component.__dict__
    return mapping_dict
```

This works but not so efficient because I am making a deepcopy of the instance every time I call the function.

My question is, why when I call `self.entity.__dict__`, `entity` becomes type `dict` instead of type `Entity`? What is the mechanism behind this? And also whats the most efficient implementation to obtain a mapping of a composite object?

Comment: `mapping_dict = self.__dict__` **does not** create a new dictionary, so the next line is actually overwriting the instance attribute. Why don't you implement e.g. [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) so you can use the object itself like a dictionary?

Comment: You don't need to deepcopy the instance; all you need is a shallow copy of the `__dict__`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jonrsharpe mentions, this:

```
mapping_dict = self.__dict__
```

does not create a copy of `self.__dict__` - it only binds the local name `mapping_dict` to the object also bound to `self.__dict__` (you definitly want to [read this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for more about python names / bindings etc).

So this next line:

```
   mapping_dict['component'] = self.component.__dict__
```

is actually the equivalent of:

```
   self.component = self.component.__dict__
```

which is obviously not what you want.

A simple solution is to create a new dict from `self.__dict__`. Since we need this for both  `Component` and `Entity`, the better solution is to factor this out to a [mixin class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin):

```
class AsDictMixin(object):
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
          k:(v.as_dict() if isinstance(v, AsDictMixin) else v) 
          for k, v in self.__dict__.items()
          }

class Component(AsDictMixin):
    def __init___(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b        

class Entity(AsDictMixin):
    def __init__(self, component, c, d):
       self.component= component
       self.c = c
       self.d = d
```

Note that this won't take computed attributes (properties etc) in account, only plain instance attributes, but I assume that it's what you want.